# Mounting an RAID0 EBS array on EC2

Tags: filesystems, mdadm, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I had a RAID 0 on two EBS volumes running fine on EC2 until the instance was stopped, a snapshot of the EBS volumes created and then restarted again. Now when I go to `mount` the RAID array I can't seem to do so.

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble -v /dev/md0 /dev/xvdj1 /dev/xvdk1
```

But when I try to `mount`:

```
$ mount -t ext4 /dev/md0 /mnt
```

I get

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** Yes, I'm sure the file system is ext4 and it has quite a bit of data on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your distro there may be an LVM layer sitting on top of your MDADM RAID array. You can confirm what type of filesystem, if any, is present on your `/dev/md0` device like so:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/md0
tune2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/md0
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Here this RAID array doesn't have any filesystem on it directly. You can see if there's a LVM layer sitting on it like so:

```
$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/md0   lvm-raid2  lvm2 a--    2.73T    0 
  /dev/sda6  VolGroup00 lvm2 a--  230.47G    0 

$ sudo vgs
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  VolGroup00   1   2   0 wz--n- 230.47G    0 
  lvm-raid2    1   1   0 wz--n-   2.73T    0 

$ sudo lvs
  LV       VG         Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  LogVol00 VolGroup00 -wi-ao 228.53G                                      
  LogVol01 VolGroup00 -wi-ao   1.94G                                      
  lvm0     lvm-raid2  -wi-ao   2.73T
```

In the above we can see that the device `/dev/md0` is a physical device that's being used by LVM. The volume group, `lvm-raid2`. This VG has one logical volume, LV, `lvm0`. So this LV is what ultimately would contain a filesystem, and is the device I would be mounting in my scenario:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/lvm-raid2/lvm0 
tune2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          285f5221-1637-4018-adf2-687a3c237f56
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              366297088
Block count:              732565504
Reserved block count:     36622312
Free blocks:              266723411
Free inodes:              366282770
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      849
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         16384
Inode blocks per group:   512
Filesystem created:       Wed Dec 16 23:35:01 2009
Last mount time:          Tue May 27 08:41:04 2014
Last write time:          Tue May 27 08:41:04 2014
Mount count:              53
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Wed Dec 16 23:35:01 2009
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:       128
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   tea
Directory Hash Seed:      c024e605-e31a-4593-ad2c-db2d80272d59
Journal backup:           inode blocks
[root@skinner ~]# tune2fs -l /dev/lvm-raid2/lvm0 | grep type
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
```

LVM also maintains device handles for mounting under `/dev/mapper` too.

```
$ sudo mount  | grep lvm0
/dev/mapper/lvm--raid2-lvm0 on /export/raid1 type ext3 (rw)
```

So you may find those referenced instead of `/dev/<LVM VG>/<LVM LV>`.